# Pthread member function with arguments

Tags: c++, pthreads

I'm trying to use pthreads with classes. I've read that the best solution to use threads with member functions is to define a static helper function and call the thread function from inside. But this requires a 'this' pointer to be passed as an argument to pthread_create. How do I implement this if my original thread function already has an argument? Is there a way to pass multiple arguments to pthread_create?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot pass multiple arguments to `pthread_create`, but you can pack multiple arguments into a `struct` that you create specifically for the purpose of packing the arguments. Make the `struct` "private" to your implementation by defining it in the cpp file, rather than in the header. Pass a pointer of that struct to `pthread_create`, then "unpack" it in the helper to call the member function.

Let's assume that the thread implementation is a member function `threadRun` defined as follows:

```
int MyClass::threadRun(int arg1, string arg2) {
    ...        // Do useful work
    return 42; // Return an important number
}
```

To call this function, define a `thread_args` `struct` like this:

```
struct thread_args {
    MyClass *instance;
    int arg1;
    string arg2;
};
```

Now your helper function can be defined as follows:

```
void* thread_helper(void *voidArgs) {
    thread_args *args = (thread_args*)voidArgs;
    int res = args->instance->threadRun(args->arg1, args->arg2);
    return new int(res); // Return an `int` pointer to pass back thread runner's results
}
```

The function that starts up the thread could look like this:

```
...
MyClass runner;
thread_args args;
args.instance = &runner;
args.arg1 = 123;
args.arg2 = "hello";
pthread_t thread_id;
int s = pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, &thread_helper, &args);
```

Comment: @WaseemAhmadNaeem Right, that's a typo - there's no `targs` anywhere else in the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

pthread_create is defined as

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                          void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

So, it takes a function pointer, e.g.

```
void *myfunction(void *argument)
```

and the `void* argument`

If you want to use it in a class, do:

1. Define a static method with the signature: `static void *myMethod(void *argument)`
2. Call pthread_create from an object (non-static) method and pass `this` as the `arg` parameter.
3. The implementation of the static method must cast the `void *argument` to a pointer of the class (a *sort-of-this*) that can be used to call other (non-static) methods of the object.

Now, depending of what other things you need to do in the thread and passing arguments to them, you can do several things:

1. Instead of passing the `this` in the `arg`, pass a different type that can contain the `this` and all the arguments.
2. Or, perhaps more OO, make those arguments, required by the thread functionaly, attributes of the class that can be set in the object before calling `pthread_create` and can be got from the *sort-of-this*

being more specific

```
class MyThread {
public:

   MyThread(int _argument): mArgument(_argument) { }

   void start() {
       pthread_create(&mThreadId, 0,&MyThreadClass::threadMethod, this);
   }

   void doThings(int x) {
       // something to be done in the thread.
   }

   static void *threadMethod(void *arg) {
       MyThread *_this=static_cast<MyThread *>(arg);
       _this->doThings(_this->getArgument());
   }

   int getArgument() const {
       return mArgument;
   }

private:
   pthread_t mThreadId;
   int mArgument;
};
```

That can be called as:

```
MyThread thread(10);
thread.start();
```

Comment: I don t seem to understand ..  _this-> getArgument() is not an argument - how could one pass an argument to the member function outside the scope of the class?